# How should I lazy-load Ext JS MVC controllers, views, store, and models?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, lazy-loading

We're using Ext JS MVC as the front-end technology of a plugin/host architecture, where one host exists and many plugins can be installed easily via xcopy. Each plugin has an Ext JS application, and each plugin registers itself on the load of the page. The overall application is a [Single Page Application (SPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

The major problem that we've encountered now, is that we have more than 10 plugins installed, and each plugin has at least 10 controllers, and more than 50 views, stores, and models. Thus when we refresh our page (F5), we should sit and wait for almost 30 seconds so that something near 200 HTTP requests get to the server, and something near 3 Megabytes of response get back.

Though caching has been applied, but this is not desirable at all. Not even for the first time. I guess even a layman would accept this argument that to get some milk, you shouldn't wait till farm, cows, barns, houses, roads, electricity, river, etc. are built.

The definite answer to this problem must be **lazy-loading** of controllers, views, stores, and models. However, we don't have a clear picture of what we have to do to get that, and we can't find a good, applicable answer on the web. Most of the discussions are only about the requirement of **lazy-loading**, but they haven't mentioned *how*. Look at this link for example:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130449-Large-Single-Page-Architecture-in-ExtJS-4.0

or this one:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-156694.html?s=aaeec1ce30acbc9cbd2615afadec982f

If we use `Ext.require` method, then we only load our controllers as simple JavaScript files, and they won't go into their hierarchy to load their stores, views, and models. We have tested that.

On the other hand, we can't find `getController()` and `ControllerManager` on Ext JS. Seems that they're gone on Ext JS 4.1.3.

Any idea on how can we load controllers dynamically based on URL parameters (we might need a route engine to parse URL and load controllers dynamically). Even a well-documented article or forum discussion with code samples can help us.

Comment: That's why I hate Ext JS. Had I asked a jQuery question, I would have gotten more than 5 answers by now.

Comment: Have you seen this blog post about lazy loading? http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/

Comment: @SaeedNeamati ha ha ha... that is not too bad :) each platform has its own strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 3):

For your problem you should load controller files on an event like menu click or etc.
with the **Ext.require**.
after you this you should initialize your controller.

I read the ExtJs source and implement a custom lazy load controllers on the below.

```
// this should run first time your application start
Ext.application({
    name: 'AppName',
    appProperty: 'appProp'
});

// below lines should run when you want to load controllers
// (for ex on menuitemclick)
var controllers = ['yourController', 'anotherController'];

Ext.require(controllers, function () {
    for (i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
        var controllerName = controllers[i].substr(controllers[i].lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (!AppName.appProp.controllers.get(controllerName)) {
            var controller = Ext.create(controllers[i], {
                application: AppName.appProp,
                id: controllerName
            });
            controller.init(AppName.appProp);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good but dirty ;) I think Sencha should make a clear solution for this common problem.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej no you're wrong. sencha till v4.1.3 doesn't have any solution for it. I check that.

Comment: It doesn't have any till now!(4.2) Indeed it doesn't have any lazy-loading strategy for its MVC pattern. I leave it for my Enterprise project. I think it needs more time to be mature

Comment: I know that extjs-4.2 released. tell me if it exist in 4.2 please.

Comment: It doesn't have MVC with Lazy Loading model.

Comment: also we can use 
    var controllerName = controllers[i].substr(controllers[i]);

Comment: also we can use
 var controllerName =     controllers[i].substr(controllers[i]);

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Ext.create()?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-create

This method will dynamically load your .js files and it seems to work well. However, it seems that there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: that's require but not enough because after create controller we should init the controller as i do in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 4.2.0, this is available.  From the [Architecting Your App](http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-2) tutorial...

> In larger applications, you might want to load additional controllers at runtime. You can do this by using the getController method.  When you load additional controllers at runtime, you have to remember to call the init method on the loaded controller manually.

```
someAction: function() {
  var controller = this.getController('AnotherController');

  // Remember to call the init method manually
  controller.init();
}
```

[Here is a link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController) to the documentation for this feature of `Ext.app.Application`.